# How to remove validations of form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery.validate plugin to validate my form that appears in popup with dynamic values. Once user click submit button error of form displayed.

Once user clicks cancel how to undo the validation that appears in form.

I used `resetForm` but still problem comes I am using `$("#form_id").validate()` with in a click function.

Comment: Try: `$('#form_id label.error').hide();`

Comment: rather than adding .validate() to form id. Add it to form class and then use jquery .removeClass() to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove validation errors then you can .remove() to remove the error messages, then remove whatever validation class from that field

```
$('input.required').removeClass('required'); // no class == no future validation
$('label.error').remove();
```

If you want to disable validation on the entire form you can also do one of the follow, though you'll still want to remove the error messages.

```
$("#form_id").validate().cancelSubmit = true; // add to click event
```

or you can add a `cancel` class to your submit button

```
<input class="cancel" type="submit" value="Submit form" />
```

or add the cancel class with jquery `$('#form_id input[type=submit]').addClass('cancel');`

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the following with `JQuery.Validate` if you just want to reset the validation on the cancel button.

```
var resetFormOnClose = function ()
{
    $('.validation-summary-errors').removeClass('validation-summary-errors').addClass('validation-summary-valid');
    $('.field-validation-error')
                .removeClass('field-validation-error')
                .addClass('field-validation-valid');

    $('.input-validation-error')
                .removeClass('input-validation-error')
                .addClass('valid');
};
```

so when the cancel button is clicked i just call the function `resetFormOnClose();` in the event handler.

what it does is finds all instances of the `error` class and replaces it with the `valid` class.

it also just hides, by adding the valid class, the `<ul></ul>` where the summary informations is displayed (if you have it enabled)